# How to typeset an array

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, arrays

I would like to produce the following:

[image]

what is the error?

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{copyrightbox}
    \begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{array}
          0.5 & -1 & -0.5
       \end{array}
    \]

 \end{document}
```

Comment: This is not an error, but you have to specify the numbers of columns with `\begin{array}{ccc}`, where `ccc` means we have 3 "c"entered columns (you can also use `l` for left and `r` for right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use the `amsmath` package, why you not use `bmatrix` environment?

using array you need to specify columns (see second equation below)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{W} = \begin{bmatrix}
                0.5 & -1 & -0.5
            \end{bmatrix}
\qquad  b=0.5
\]
or 
\[
\mathbf{W} = [\begin{array}{ccc} % <--- added columns' types
                0.5 & -1 & -0.5
              \end{array}]    
\qquad  b=0.5
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how written b=0.5 in the same line?

Comment: this was not very clear in your question, now added.